# Laptop overheating after 1 minute from boot

Tags: laptop, cooling

As in the title, my laptop overheats at the first minute of boot up. It does not shutdown because the maximum temp. is **100° C**, I think. The problem is that it's still reaching **90° C**. I cleaned it up and re-applied thermal compound, nothing changed. The question is: why? I suspect the fan is malfunctioning, but I don't want to waste money as I'm not sure.

Laptop model is **HP Compaq Presario CQ56-110SL**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we do not know what kind of Notebook you are talking about I can only give the usual advice.

1. Open up your notebook until you can clearly see the fans.
2. Now simply turn it on and check on what is running hot and why?

Also make sure to check what is running hot. I guess the CPU but maybe the Heatpipe is just not applied correctly or not enough pressure or not enough Thermal Paste.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check. Meanwhile I added the laptop model in the question

Comment: I just had to clean it deeper and add more thermal compound.